# I wonder how to move the cursor between PyQt5 widgets

Tags: pyqt5

I want to move the cursor like the two images below.
The widget at the top is qlineEdit, and the widget at the bottom is qtextEdit.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Qt Docs: [setFocus()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFocus-1).

Answer (score 0):

Design your gui with the qt designer and there set the tap order according to your needs.